# How to display zero after the decimal on whole numbers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a float that i want to display as 2.0 (or the entire float) But it always displays as 2 (without the decimals) when I use the float directly in razor.
I have tried stuff like

```
float result = 2.0F;
float number = float.Parse(result.ToString("0.0"));
//or: (float)Math.Round(result, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

But i can't seem to display results that have zero after the decimal as anything but whole numbers in html.

Why do I have to convert it to a string to be able to show it correctly in razor?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier use e.g. "N1" format when converting to string.

Comment: Why do you _parse_ it back to float?

Comment: because i want to be able to display the float in razor, without converting it to a string to display the zero decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with formatting string.

```
float.ToString("0.0");
```

or

```
float.ToString("N1");
```

If you want **more digits on display**, you can increase Zero's after dot or you can change N1 value to N2

Example:

```
float.ToString("0.00");
```

or

```
float.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you are just converting the result to float back.

```
float result = 2.0F;
string numberstr = result.ToString("0.0");
```

or you can use:

```
float result = 2.0F;
Console.WriteLine(result .ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a display of few of the many possible options.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var f = 2.0F;
    Print(f);

    f = 2.12345F;
    Print(f);
}

public static void Print(float f) {
    Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("0.0###"));
    Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("0.0"));
    Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("N1"));
    Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("G29"));
}
```

Output:

```
2.0
2.0
2.0
2
2.1235
2.1
2.1
2.12345004
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to display it as a string then use:

```
float result = 2.0F;
string resultString = result.ToString("N1");
```